# Print values of constraint at each iteration during optimization

Tags: drake

How can we do this from Pydrake? Print values of constraint at each iteration during optimization

EDIT 1:

I tried:

```
def update(n):
    print(n)

prog.AddVisualizationCallback(update, n)
```

in accordance with the example here at the bottom: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/debug_mathematical_program.ipynb

But it spat out this error:

```
    prog.AddVisualizationCallback(update, n)
TypeError: AddVisualizationCallback(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.MathematicalProgram, arg0: Callable[[numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[m, 1]]], None], arg1: numpy.ndarray[object[m, 1]]) -> pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.Binding[VisualizationCallback]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few possibilities:

- You can use [AddVisualizationCallback](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_mathematical_program.html#a67626d45d9a119d01e1c046ad89ee556) to make effectively an empty generic constraint that gets called on each iteration.
- You might also want to increase the solver verbosity level (see the “debugging mathematical programs” tutorial) so that the solver itself prints some progress info.
- Depending on what sort of constraint you’re thinking about, you could potentially just implement the constraint itself as a python method (with a `print` statement inside) instead of whatever you’re doing to add it right now.

Comment: I just tried the VisualizationCallback and updated my initial post

Comment: Also tried increasing the verbosity, but couldn't get it to show the decision variables

Comment: The error message seems pretty good to me.  Presumably your `n` is not a *vector* of decision variables?